# Error after adding django form-wizard into urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls, django-formwizard

I have this code in urls.py of my app:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('john_shop.checkout.views',
    (r'^wizard/$', ContactWizard.as_view([CheckoutForm, PaymentForm]),'checkout_wizard'),
)
```

If FormWizard stays uncommented, I get this error:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is requiredRequest Method:    GET
Request URL:    http://john-shop.ru/category/new-balance-501/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _populate, line 258
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
```

What can cause this problem? I know that Error says nothing about urls.py, but still, if I comment that string out, site works perfect.

P.S. I need it to be named to get redirect from a cart and proceed user through the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it wrong. Here's a correct one:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^ wizard/$', ContactWizard.as_view([CheckoutForm, PaymentForm])),
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#hooking-the-wizard-into-a-urlconf

Comment: Changed to: 
`urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^wizard/$', ContactWizard.as_view([CheckoutForm, PaymentForm]),'checkout'),
)`

and I still get the same error. I guess thats because of name of the url, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Stupid question: if you comment out the urls line, do you still get the error?